# Magento 2: Generate a HTML or PHP file from controller

Tags: magento2, php, html

I want to generate and download a html or a php file when a controller is called. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Controller\Result;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory;
use Magento\Framework\HTTP\Mime as HTTPMime;

class Download implements HttpGetActionInterface
{
    protected Context     $context;
    protected FileFactory $fileFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        FileFactory $fileFactory
    ) {
        $this->context     = $context;
        $this->fileFactory = $fileFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        // your generate logic
        $fileName = 'your_file.html';
        $fileContent = 'content of your HTML file';

        return $this->fileFactory->create(
            $fileName,
            $fileContent,
            DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,
            HTTPMime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM
        );
    }
}
```